# How to download SharePoint Audit Logs from Office 365

Tags: auditing, audit-log-reports

My organisation has a requirement that audit / security logs need to be kept for at least one year. In office 365 the logs available in the Audit Log Search are only kept for 90 days.

I am trying to find the simplest possible solution where we can download the logs to be stored locally. Ideally a product we can buy before we have to custom develop something.

I have looked at using the Search-UnifiedAuditLog powershell command but this does count as custom dev and I would also need to split the JSON return into individual columns.

The ideal end result would be a simple CSV file containing the days worth of results.

Has anyone seen anything like this available?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a CSV **Audit log search** file directly from Office 365 :

1. Go to **Admin Center** then Click on **Security and Compliance**
   like image below:

[image]

2. Then select **Audit Log Search** and search by Date then you can Save or Export your Results in CSV file :

[image]

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is manually and needs someone to select the correct filters and date range each time. I would like to automate that.